# Raspberry Pi4 extension to PCIe

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-4

Is it possible to extend the Raspberry Pi 4 to provide a PCIe connection? I have a PC which has as only purpose to play music using this Soundcard (no Linux drivers that work well) "PCI Express X-Fi Titanium Fatal1ty Pro Series" by Creative and I am happy with the sound. But the PC takes away a lot of space. So I would like to know if there is a possibility to run Windows 7/10 on a Raspberry Pi and extend it by a PCIe lane?

Comment: Are sound cards even relevant these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone (see links below) has managed to connect a PCIE card to a Raspberry Pi 4 by desoldering the USB chip and connecting to the board, so it's kind of possible if you like soldering and damaging your Pi.  The Pi 4 has one set of PCIE lanes, that is used for USB-3 support.

I don't think Windows is available for newer Pis though.  Windows IOT core was released for Pi 2&3, but hasn't had update since 2017?

http://mloduchowski.com/en/blog/raspberry-pi-4-b-pci-express/

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20399555

Comment: Looks cool, but from the article I get that by doing this mode you lose the USB ports and some (most?) of PCIE hardware doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Since PCI-e bus is not routed to any connector on the board, it's pretty much impossible to connect anything to it. Hand-soldering a high-speed bus will ruin the signals even if you manage to tap into the right spots.

Get a board which actually supports PCI-e, such as ClearFog Pro.